# Achieving communication between HighCharts and server.R

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts, shiny, rcharts

I am trying to show a table(or probably another plot) in a separate div element when one of the bars on the HighCharts bar plot is clicked. I am using rCharts from Shiny package to create a HighCharts plot.

In my experimentation till now, I came across two possible psths.

**Path 1**

I tried to make use of click function in the HighCharts bar/column plot API. I tried doing this.

> ```
> observe({  
>     output$plot <- renderChart2({
>                        a <- hPlot(x="id",y="sequence",data=myData,type="column")
>                        a$tooltip( animation = 'true', formatter = "#! function() {return '<b>' + 'Frequency of tag_id ' + this.x + '</b>' + ' is ' + this.y;} !#")
>                        a$plotOptions(series = list(color = '#388E8E'),column = list(dataLabels = list(enabled = T, rotation = -90, align = 'right', color = '#FFFFFF', x = 4, y = 10),cursor = 'pointer', point=list(events = list(click = func))))
>                  return(a)
>         }) session$sendCustomMessage(type="data", rg1) )}
> ```

and for function **func** (which is supposed to invoke when a bar is clicked)

> ```
> func <- "#! function() {
>         Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('data', function(rg1) {
>                 var data1 = rg1.series            
>                 $('.container_subcat').highcharts({
>                         chart: {
>                                 type: 'column',
>                         }
>                         xAxis: { categories:(data1) },
>                 title: {
>                                 text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
>                 },
>                 series: [{  data :(data1)
>                         }]
>                 }); 
> })} !#"
> ```

I am sure that is not the way to bind data, but I added a lot of code to the above code after looking into several online sources. None of my attempts make me smile. Also, I think if I should proceed in this way, I need to change the data into Java script readable format from R dataframe (`rg1` above is a dataframe), but no clue when and where should the conversion be done.

**Path 2**

I used `session$sendCustomMessage()` and `Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler()` functions.

**server.R -> app.js**

> In server.R: `observe({ session$sendCustomMessage(type="newdata", data
>   })`
>
> In app.js: `Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("newdata", function(data1) {
>   ... });`

**chart.js -> server.R**

> In app.js: `Shiny.onInputChange("select", this.data.ele);`
>
> In server.R: `current <- input$select`

The above mechanism works fine with all the buttons or other UI elements we have in HTML. But, I am trying to achieve the same mechanism when a bar on the barplot is clicked. I have no clue how to extract each bar from the barplot and use it like we used it in `current <- input$select`. So, it's basically establishing the communication between the HighCharts UI element(which inturn is shiny/rCharts element) and the server to get the data when an element is clicked.

I came across Shiny input and output bindings and had hard time understanding them and not sure whether they are useful in my particular situation. Can someone walk me through a method/solution which can solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case any one is looking for answer, head over to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31119432/using-global-data-in-high-charts-point-click-custom-function-in-r-shiny), the method using paste works like charm and passes data to the javascript function.