# Using global data in High Charts point click custom function in R Shiny

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, rcharts

I am trying to show a different table or plot in a different div when a bar on a a bar plot is clicked. I have come this far.

**server.R**

```
    library(shiny)
    shinyServer(function(input,output,session) {
    custom_data = # a data frame in R
    barclick_func <- "#! function() {
                            var cats = ['100','200','3000','4000'];
                            var datum = [20,40,30,10];
                    }       
                    $('#container_subcat').highcharts({
                            chart: {
                                    type: 'column',
                            },
                            xAxis: { categories:cats },
                            series: [{data :datum}]
                    }); 
    } !#"

    output$my_plot <- renderChart2({
                    a <- hPlot(x="id",y="variable",data=custom_data,type="column")
                    a$tooltip( animation = 'true', formatter = "#! function() {return '<b>' + 'Frequency of tag_id ' + this.x + '</b>' + ' is ' + this.y;} !#")
                    a$plotOptions(series = list(color = '#388E8E'),column = list(dataLabels = list(enabled = T, rotation =-90, align = 'right', color = '#FFFFFF', x = 4, y = 10),
cursor = 'pointer', point = list(events = list(click = barclick_func))))
                    return(a)
            })
    })
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
require(rCharts)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "custom.css"),
    tags$script(src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git2.min.js"),
  ),
  titlePanel("Test"),
  fluidRow(  
      showOutput("my_plot","highcharts")
  ),
  div(id="container_subcat",style="min-width: 310-px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto; margin-top:100px;")
 )
))
```

In the above server.R script, in `barclick_func()` function, the data(variables `cats` and `datum`) is hardcoded. The above app works as expected when a bar is clicked, another plot pops up properly with the data.

But, if I want to use another data, that is if I have another data frame in R and want to use that data frame in `barclick_func()`, the console is throwing an error that the variable is not recognized and if I look at the type of that variable, it shows as 'undefined'. Can anyone suggest how to send data to the javascript function in this particular case. Ideally, my desired code is this.

**server.R**

```
    library(shiny)
    shinyServer(function(input,output,session) {
    custom_data = # a data frame in R

    custom_data2 = # another data frame in R for which I wanna shoe a plot when the bar is clicked.

    barclick_func <- "#! function() { 

                            var cats = #subsetting custom_data2 ;
                            var datum = #subsetting custom_data2 ;

                      }       
                    $('#container_subcat').highcharts({
                            chart: {
                                    type: 'column',
                            },
                            xAxis: { categories:cats },
                            series: [{data :datum}]
                    }); 
    } !#"

    output$my_plot <- renderChart2({
                    a <- hPlot(x="id",y="variable",data=custom_data,type="column")
                    a$tooltip( animation = 'true', formatter = "#! function() {return '<b>' + 'Frequency of tag_id ' + this.x + '</b>' + ' is ' + this.y;} !#")
                    a$plotOptions(series = list(color = '#388E8E'),column = list(dataLabels = list(enabled = T, rotation =-90, align = 'right', color = '#FFFFFF', x = 4, y = 10), 
cursor = 'pointer', point = list(events = list(click = barclick_func))))
                    return(a)
            })
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `paste` to add the data to your `barclick_func`.

For example:

```
         custom_data2 = data.frame(cats=c(100,200,3000,400),datum=c(20,40,30,10))


        barclick_func <- paste("#! function() { 

        var cats = ",paste('[',paste(custom_data2$cats,collapse=','),']',sep=''),"
        var datum = ",paste('[',paste(custom_data2$datum,collapse=','),']',sep=''),"; 

        }       
        $('#container_subcat').highcharts({
        chart: {
        type: 'column',
        },
        xAxis: { categories:cats },
        series: [{data :datum}]
        }); 
        } !#")
```

Should give the same `barclick_func` as in your hardcoded version.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can pass data to javascript function now. You ended my week long search. I didn't know that paste has this capability of passing data.